# I am trying to inject a partial template in Angular that contains a graph

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-scope, d3plus

I am creating an Angular application in ASP.NET with partial templates. When I select the menu, and click "Employees", a controller calls a webservice and returns the correct JSON data, and I store it in `$scope.message`. I've displayed `$scope.message` on the screen, and everything works.

However, I want to feed `$scope.message` as data source to a D3plus boxplot graph stored in a partial template called `employees.html`. It does not seem to be working. Perhaps I am making an obvious mistake and would greatly appreciate the community's help. Thank you! Here is mu code:

Webform1.aspx (webform):

```
...
<body onload="loadPikaday()" data-ng-app="Demo">

    <%-- Header --%>
    <div id="topBanner" class="topBanner">
        <div id="menu" class="menu">
            Report from: &emsp; 
            <input id="startDate" size="6" type="text" data-ng-model="startDate" /> &emsp; To &emsp; 
            <input id="endDate" size="6" type="text" data-ng-model="endDate" />&emsp; 

           <%-- Dropdown menu --%>
            <div class="dropdown">
            <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">MENU</button>
                <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#/cases">Cases</a>
                    <a href="#/protocols">Protocols</a>
                    <a href="#/employees">Employees</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>


    <%-- Where html is injected--%>
    <div data-ng-view=""></div>

</body>
...
```

myScript.js (Angular module):

```
/// <reference path="angular.min.js" />

var app = angular.module("Demo", ['ngRoute'])
                 .config(function ($routeProvider) {
                     $routeProvider
                         .when('/cases', { // Root: initialize with cases
                             templateUrl: 'templates/cases.html',
                             controller: 'casesController'
                         })
                         .when('/protocols', { // Root: initialize with cases
                             templateUrl: 'templates/protocols.html',
                             controller: 'protocolsController'
                         })
                         .when('/employees', {
                             templateUrl: 'templates/employees.html',
                             controller: 'employeesController'
                         })
                 })
                .controller('casesController', function ($scope) {
                    $scope.message = "Cases!";
                })
                .controller('protocolsController', function ($scope) {
                    $scope.message = "This is the protocols page!";
                })
                .controller('employeesController', function ($scope, $http) {
                    $http.get('dataWebService.asmx/getTotalForDateIntervalEmployees', {
                        params: { startDate: '2015-01-01', endDate: '2016-08-01' }
                    })
                    .then(function (response) {
                        $scope.message = response.data;
                    })
                });
```

employees.html (injected partial template):

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="//d3plus.org/js/d3.js"></script>
<script src="//d3plus.org/js/d3plus.js"></script>

<div id="viz"></div>

<script>

  var data = {{message}};

  var visualization = d3plus.viz()
   .container("#viz")
   .data(data)
   .type("box")
   .id("name")
   .x("building")
   .y("total")
   .time(false)
   .ui([{
       "label": "Visualization Type",
       "method": "type",
       "value": ["scatter", "box"]
   }])
   .draw()

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example using a directive...

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.data = [];

    $http.get('/data').then(function(data) {
        $scope.data = data.data;
    });
});

app.directive('chart', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            data: '=',
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, atts) {

            var svg = d3.select(elem[0]).append('svg'),
                chart = svg.append('g');

            scope.$watch('data', function(data) {
                chart.selectAll('*').remove();

                if (data.length) {
                    updateChartData(data);
                }
            });

            function updateChartData(data) {
                // add all your d3 code here...
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Then you can bind the data with something like

```
<chart data="data"></chart>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help!!! I am trying to learn AngularJS, but got stuck there for a long time! I truly appreciate your time! :D

Answer (score 1):

You're going about this all wrong, I'm afraid to say. You should not have javascript in your template and then use angular to inject values into that script. Angular is based on the MVC principle and you are mixing up controller and view here. I'd strongly suggest using an angular directive to wrap your d3 functionality: like for example this: https://github.com/mariohmol/angular-d3plus. Simple principle here: never, ever have js code in templates in Angular.

Comment: Thank you VERY much for your help. I am new to AngularJS, so I greatly appreciate you explaining my obvious mistake. It sounds corny, but I learned something important today! :D

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, The controller is used to bind data, and the directive is used to instruct "how to build a new chart", right?

Comment: Hi! It works great except that my boxplots are extremely faint. I was wondering if you could please look at my new post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39455342/d3plus-boxplots-dont-appear-when-i-use-angulars-directive-angular-d3plus

Comment: You're welcome. With regards to your question about controllers and directives, yes controllers bind data to the view. Directives are Angular's way of having reusable components. They encapsulate elements of both view and controller, and indeed can have their own controller. They are also used in Angular for lower-level DOM manipulations. If you find yourself doing anything that looks like (or uses) jQuery, you should probably be using a directive. (Though most of the time you shouldn't need to manipulate the DOM directly if you're using the framework correctly.)